# How to change a particular color in an image?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image-processing, core-graphics, pixel

My question is if I have a Lion image just I want to change the color of the lion alone not the background color. For that I referred this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223340/iphone-how-do-you-color-an-image) but it turns the color of whole image. Moreover the image is not looking great. I need the color change like photoshop. whether it is possible to do this in coregraphics or I have to use any other library.

EDIT : I need the color change to be like [iQuikColor](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/live-splash-free-selective-color-grayscale-effects/id359017259) app

[image]

Comment: nice question, if u got the perfect answer, i'll use that

Comment: i'm also having the same issue, i posted the question [colorfill issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124308/filling-a-portion-of-an-image-with-color),

Comment: hi did you got any idea in this

Comment: I am trying jano's answer.. now got struck in 3 rd point...

Comment: @Rocotilos can you help please? I am trying for the same..

Comment: I am looking to develop a similar functionality .. except I am trying to make a virtual wall painting .. How did you do this ? Some tip/tutorial will be appreciated

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**See answers below instead. Mine doesn't provide a complete solution.**

---

Here is the sketch of a possible solution using OpenCV:

- Convert the image from RGB to HSV using `cvCvtColor` (we only want to change the hue).
- Isolate a color with `cvThreshold` specifying a certain tolerance (you want a range of colors, not one flat color).
- Discard areas of color below a minimum size using a blob detection library like [cvBlobsLib](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/cvBlobsLib). This will get rid of dots of the similar color in the scene.
- Mask the color with `cvInRangeS` and use the resulting mask to apply the new hue.
- `cvMerge` the new image with the new hue with an image composed by the saturation and brightness channels that you saved in step one.

There are several OpenCV iOS ports in the net, eg: http://www.eosgarden.com/en/opensource/opencv-ios/overview/ I haven't tried this myself, but seems a good research direction.

Comment: Hi jano, I am stuck in step:4, I have applied cvInRangeS function and I got threashold image but not sure what do you mean by  "use the resulting mask to apply the new hue." and how to use in step:5? can you please elaborate more about it

Answer (score 43):

This took quite a while to figure out, mainly because I wanted to get it up and running in Swift using Core Image and CIColorCube.

@Miguel's explanation is spot on about the way you need to replace a "Hue angle range" with another "Hue angle range". You can read his post above for details on what a Hue Angle Range is.

I made a quick app that replaces a default blue truck below, with whatever you choose on Hue slider.

[image]

You can slide the slider to tell the app what color Hue you want to replace the blue with.

I'm hardcoding the Hue range to be 60 degrees, which typically seems to encompass most of a particular color but you can edit that if you need to.

[image]

[image]

Notice that it does not color the tires or the tail lights because that's outside of the 60 degree range of the truck's default blue hue, but it does handle shading appropriately.

First you need code to convert RGB to HSV (Hue value):

```
func RGBtoHSV(r : Float, g : Float, b : Float) -> (h : Float, s : Float, v : Float) {
    var h : CGFloat = 0
    var s : CGFloat = 0
    var v : CGFloat = 0
    let col = UIColor(red: CGFloat(r), green: CGFloat(g), blue: CGFloat(b), alpha: 1.0)
    col.getHue(&h, saturation: &s, brightness: &v, alpha: nil)
    return (Float(h), Float(s), Float(v))
}
```

Then you need to convert HSV to RGB. You want to use this when you discover a hue that in your desired hue range (aka, a color that's the same blue hue of the default truck) to save off any adjustments you make.

```
func HSVtoRGB(h : Float, s : Float, v : Float) -> (r : Float, g : Float, b : Float) {
    var r : Float = 0
    var g : Float = 0
    var b : Float = 0
    let C = s * v
    let HS = h * 6.0
    let X = C * (1.0 - fabsf(fmodf(HS, 2.0) - 1.0))
    if (HS >= 0 && HS < 1) {
        r = C
        g = X
        b = 0
    } else if (HS >= 1 && HS < 2) {
        r = X
        g = C
        b = 0
    } else if (HS >= 2 && HS < 3) {
        r = 0
        g = C
        b = X
    } else if (HS >= 3 && HS < 4) {
        r = 0
        g = X
        b = C
    } else if (HS >= 4 && HS < 5) {
        r = X
        g = 0
        b = C
    } else if (HS >= 5 && HS < 6) {
        r = C
        g = 0
        b = X
    }
    let m = v - C
    r += m
    g += m
    b += m
    return (r, g, b)
}
```

Now you simply loop through a full RGBA color cube and "adjust" any colors in the "default blue" hue range with those from your newly desired hue. Then use Core Image and the CIColorCube filter to apply your adjusted color cube to the image.

```
func render() {
    let centerHueAngle: Float = 214.0/360.0 //default color of truck body blue
    let destCenterHueAngle: Float = slider.value
    let minHueAngle: Float = (214.0 - 60.0/2.0) / 360 //60 degree range = +30 -30
    let maxHueAngle: Float = (214.0 + 60.0/2.0) / 360
    var hueAdjustment = centerHueAngle - destCenterHueAngle
    let size = 64
    var cubeData = [Float](count: size * size * size * 4, repeatedValue: 0)
    var rgb: [Float] = [0, 0, 0]
    var hsv: (h : Float, s : Float, v : Float)
    var newRGB: (r : Float, g : Float, b : Float)
    var offset = 0
    for var z = 0; z < size; z++ {
        rgb[2] = Float(z) / Float(size) // blue value
        for var y = 0; y < size; y++ {
            rgb[1] = Float(y) / Float(size) // green value
            for var x = 0; x < size; x++ {
                rgb[0] = Float(x) / Float(size) // red value
                hsv = RGBtoHSV(rgb[0], g: rgb[1], b: rgb[2])
                if hsv.h < minHueAngle || hsv.h > maxHueAngle {
                    newRGB.r = rgb[0]
                    newRGB.g = rgb[1]
                    newRGB.b = rgb[2]
                } else {
                    hsv.h = destCenterHueAngle == 1 ? 0 : hsv.h - hueAdjustment //force red if slider angle is 360
                    newRGB = HSVtoRGB(hsv.h, s:hsv.s, v:hsv.v)
                }
                cubeData[offset]   = newRGB.r
                cubeData[offset+1] = newRGB.g
                cubeData[offset+2] = newRGB.b
                cubeData[offset+3] = 1.0
                offset += 4
            }
        }
    }
    let data = NSData(bytes: cubeData, length: cubeData.count * sizeof(Float))
    let colorCube = CIFilter(name: "CIColorCube")!
    colorCube.setValue(size, forKey: "inputCubeDimension")
    colorCube.setValue(data, forKey: "inputCubeData")
    colorCube.setValue(ciImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    if let outImage = colorCube.outputImage {
        let context = CIContext(options: nil)
        let outputImageRef = context.createCGImage(outImage, fromRect: outImage.extent)
        imageView.image = UIImage(CGImage: outputImageRef)
    }
}
```

You can download the [sample project here](https://github.com/trav-ma/TMReplaceColorHue).

Comment: **Outstanding** post! (voted.) Now I just need to find the time to download the project and figure out how your converting your HSV color ranges into a color cube. Why not make the input hue a slider as well, and also the hue angle range? That would make for a more flexible sample, and shouldn't be that hard to do.

Comment: I wrote a project a while back (pre-swift) that interrogates iOS for a list of available CI filters and builds a UI to collect the inputs to try most of them out. I didn't spend the time to figure out how to build a color cube, so it was one of the ones my app doesn't support. Your post might give me the nudge I need to add support for the color cube filter. The results certainly look very good.

Comment: What do you mean by a "white or gray hue"? Do you mean creating a monochrome car? You probably need to adjust the saturation value in the destination color range rather than the hue value. I'm guessing you'd still use a hue angle range for the input colors, and then knock down the saturation on the output colors.

Comment: How did you figure out how to generate the color cube data? The Xcode docs on the CIColorCube filter leave a **great** deal to the imagination, to the point that I could not make any sense of them.

Comment: Can you point me to some docs that explain how to construct a color cube? From your code it looks like each coordinate in the cube contains values ranging from 0 to 1 in R/G/B/A. Are the x,y,z coordinates of each point the source color value, and the value stored there is the output color? And then it interpolates values between?

Comment: You are spot on, I changed the "white" toggle to be "monochrome" toggle and when it's on I set the saturation to 0 and adjust the HSV.V value instead of the Hue and it worked like a charm. Updated the git project.

Comment: About your question, unfortunately, the make up of the RGBA color cube is still confusing to me. It seems to be a 64 x 64 x 64 "cube" that represents the hue color circle. You simply loop through every single color in the circle and make any adjustments you want, then apply that new cube to the filter.  I took mine from Apple's site, also, you can see how people can do their hardcoded formats here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798368/formatting-cicolorcube-data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89979/discussion-between-duncan-c-and-william-t).

Comment: That's amazing. Thank you so much!

Comment: That`s quite a nice summary. The same thing if I want to do in live camera feed of iOS, how should that be done ?

Comment: Can anyone tell me what to do to replace white and black color? Because when I change the default hue in the example to a value of white or black, then it doesn't work. But only for those two colors.

Answer (score 15):

I'm going to make the assumption that you know how to perform these basic operations, so these won't be included in my solution:

- load an image
- get the RGB value of a given pixel of the loaded image
- set the RGB value of a given pixel
- display a loaded image, and/or save it back to disk.

First of all, let's consider how you can describe the source and destination colors. Clearly you can't specify these as exact RGB values, since a photo will have slight variations in color. For example, the green pixels in the truck picture you posted are not all exactly the same shade of green. The RGB color model isn't very good at expressing basic color characteristics, so you will get much better results if you convert the pixels to HSL. [Here](http://axonflux.com/handy-rgb-to-hsl-and-rgb-to-hsv-color-model-c) are C functions to convert RGB to HSL and back.

The HSL color model describes three aspects of a color:

1. Hue - the main perceived color - i.e. red, green, orange, etc.
2. Saturation - how "full" the color is - i.e. from full color to no color at all
3. Lightness - how bright the color is

So for example, if you wanted to find all the green pixels in a picture, you will convert each pixel from RGB to HSL, then look for H values that correspond to green, with some tolerance for "near green" colors. Below is a Hue chart, from Wikipedia:

[image]

So in your case you will be looking at pixels that have a Hue of 120 degrees +/- some amount. The bigger the range the more colors will get selected. If you make your range too wide you will start seeing yellow and cyan pixels getting selected, so you'll have to find the right range, and you may even want to offer the user of your app controls to select this range.

In addition to selecting by Hue, you may want to allow ranges for Saturation and Lightness, so that you can optionally put more limits to the pixels that you want to select for colorization.

Finally, you may want to offer the user the ability to draw a "lasso selection" so that specific parts of the picture can be left out of the colorization. This is how you could tell the app that you want the body of the green truck, but not the green wheel.

Once you know which pixels you want to modify it's time to alter their color.

The easiest way to colorize the pixels is to just change the Hue, leaving the Saturation and Lightness from the original pixel. So for example, if you want to make green pixels magenta you will be adding 180 degrees to all the Hue values of the selected pixels (making sure you use modulo 360 math).

If you wanted to get more sophisticated, you can also apply changes to Saturation and that will give you a wider range of tones you can go to. I think the Lightness is better left alone, you may be able to make small adjustments and the image will still look good, but if you go too far away from the original you may start seeing hard edges where the process pixels border with background pixels.

Once you have the colorized HSL pixel you just convert it back to RGB and write it back to the image.

I hope this helps. A final comment I should make is that Hue values in code are typically recorded in the 0-255 range, but many applications show them as a color wheel with a range of 0 to 360 degrees. Keep that in mind!

Answer (score 1):

Can I suggest you look into using [OpenCV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV)? It's an open source image manipulation library, and it's got an iOS port too. There are plenty of blog posts about how to use it and set it up.

It has a whole heap of functions that will help you do a good job of what you're attempting. You *could* do it just using CoreGraphics, but the end result isn't going to look nearly as good as OpenCV would.

It was developed by some folks at MIT, so as you might expect it does a pretty good job at things like edge detection and object tracking. I remember reading a blog about how to separate a certain color from a picture with OpenCV - the examples showed a pretty good result. See [here](http://www.aishack.in/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/hsv-thresholding.jpg) for an example. From there I can't imagine it would be a massive job to actually change the separated color to something else.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a CoreGraphics operation for this, and I don't see a suitable CoreImage filter for this. If that's correct, then here's a push in the right direction:

Assuming you have a `CGImage` (or a `uiImage.CGImage`):

- Begin by creating a new `CGBitmapContext`
- Draw the source image to the bitmap context
- Get a handle to the bitmap's pixel data

Learn how the buffer is structured so you could properly populate a 2D array of pixel values which have the form:

```
typedef struct t_pixel {
  uint8_t r, g, b, a;
} t_pixel;
```

Then create the color to locate:

```
const t_pixel ColorToLocate = { 0,0,0,255 }; // << black, opaque
```

And its substitution value:

```
const t_pixel SubstitutionColor = { 255,255,255,255 }; // << white, opaque
```

- Iterate over the bitmap context's pixel buffer, creating `t_pixel`s.
- When you find a pixel which matches `ColorToLocate`, replace the source values with the values in `SubstitutionColor`.
- Create a new `CGImage` from the `CGBitmapContext`.

That's the easy part! All that does is takes a `CGImage`, replace *exact* color matches, and produces a new `CGImage`.

What you want is more sophisticated. For this task, you will want a good edge detection algorithm.

I've not used this app you have linked. If it's limited to a few colors, then they may simply be swapping channel values, paired with edge detection (keep in mind that buffers may also be represented in multiple color models - not just RGBA).

If (in the app you linked) the user can choose an arbitrary colors, values, and edge thresholds, then you will have to use real blending and edge detection. If you need to see how this is accomplished, you may want to check out a package such as [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org) (it's an open image editor) - they have the algos to detect edges and choose by color.

Comment: I too tried like this only.. but it takes time..May be I have to use an efficient algorithm.

Comment: @Trisha I'd imagine a good implementation would take time for a full size image. But yes, the edge detection will likely take some time to calculate. On modern hardware, you could reasonably divide the processing among one or two secondary threads. As you say, the algo's also quite important.