# Changing the color of selected pixel in Image

Tags: iphone

I want to make the black line of the image into red or any other color.

[image]

Or can say want to generate the colourful QR code.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I have outlined the process [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046643/how-to-change-a-particular-color-in-an-image/8077281#8077281). You can stop at "That's the easy part!". That question asked for something far more complex, but the 'easy part' is all you will need because you have 2 colors.

Here's the meat of it:

- Get a handle to the bitmap's pixel data
- Learn how the buffer is structured so you *could* properly populate a 2D array of pixel values which have the form:

  typedef struct t_pixel {
    uint8_t r, g, b, a;
  } t_pixel;

Then create the color to locate:

```
const t_pixel ColorToLocate = { 0,0,0,255 }; // << black, opaque
```

And its substitution value:

```
const t_pixel SubstitutionColor = { 255,0,0,255 }; // << red, opaque
```

Iterate over the bitmap context's pixel buffer, creating `t_pixels`.

When you find a pixel which matches `ColorToLocate`, replace the source values with the values in `SubstitutionColor`.