# How to apply filter to image in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, core-image, imagefilter

Today I've searched a lot about it, found something but I'm still confusing.

For example, I have the next filter:

[image]

The result need to be:

[image]

How can I apply it to my image?

I know how to apply such type of effects as: `PhotoEffectNoir`, or `CIPhotoEffectChrome`, but how can I apply this matrix(or I do not know how to call it) to my UIImage?

Can anyone help me with a little example?

Comment: What is this "filter"? Is it a kernel? What do you want the result to be?

Comment: @jtbandes it's a "Ancient" effect filter. I've updated the question

Answer (score 2):

This will be just a hint of an answer for now; I'll come back with more details as I have time.

Your first image is a color lookup table (aka CLUT), sometimes also called a color cube. It's a representation of a three-dimensional array where the x, y, and z coordinates are the r, g, and b components of an input color, and the value at a given xyz coordinate is the output color for that particular rgb input. (Because it's being stored in a 2D image, the 3D table is split into slices.)

You can use a CLUT for filtering in Core Image with the [CIColorCube](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIColorCube) filter. The trick to it is in converting your CLUT image to the right format to pass as a parameter to that filter.

You can find some examples of *constructing* (rather than converting an image to) a color cube [in Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_filer_recipes/ci_filter_recipes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH4-SW2) and [elsewhere on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15798368).

Comment: I did something here: http://pastebin.com/vpJcqs3e, but when I apply my LUT is changes my image but hardly considerably, like alpha 0.1. Can you help me to fix this? I do not know what is the problem

Comment: here is a new version of my code: http://pastebin.com/URJFTXgF, it still does not work =/

Comment: can you help me, please?