# replace all red pixels in apple image with green green, including gradient red ios

Tags: ios, opencv, image-processing

I am doing change color of my apple shown below:

[image]

to change all red colors to green and all yellow to orange. My problem is how to select all kind of red color and how to select all kind of yellow to apply new effect or color.

Any help please.

Thanks

Comment: It's not about changing ONLY the red color, you need to also alias orange, etc.

Comment: @perfanoff sry, i didn't get your point. van you please explain?

Comment: Basically you want to preserve gradients in the image instead of sharp borders and this is the main challenge

Comment: @perfanoff yes, i am trying to do the same.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046643/how-to-change-a-particular-color-in-an-image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to convert the RGB colors to HSB/HSV (Hue, Saturation, Brightness/Value). The hue value is the color.

For converting red to green, for instance, you'll want to figure out which numeric hue value represents red and which one represents green, then figure out a threshold. For every pixel where the hue is close to red (within your threshold), you move the hue to green.

Comment: yes, its working and i done it. Thanks a lot. And i add my code to my previous question as @Brad larson marked it duplicate of.