# how change a part of image color no the entire image

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimageview, uicolor

what I want to do is change only the black color of my original image to another color, and keep for example white color of my `image`

what I have tried is:

```
       cell.iconeEcoute?.image =     cell.iconeEcoute?.image!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate)
       cell.iconeEcoute?.tintColor = colorHexIcone
```

But this code change the entire `image` **color**, and I want to keep green `color` and replace only black color in the `image`

any help would be appreciated

Comment: The answer to this question should be able to help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046643/how-to-change-a-particular-color-in-an-image/32638622#32638622

Comment: `UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate` will always change the color if the alpha is 1.0. It does not matter if your color is red, black or white. Any other color that have alpha < 1.0 will be treated as transparent.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by taking separate View. Then give different color and alpha as you want. and you will see that part in different color.

Comment: you have a example ? i'm not sure i understand what you say

Comment: take view as newView = UIView(frame(CGRect(size you want different in your image)))  simply search on google for adding view and its property. I have example but In all cases you need different views

Comment: (size you want different in your image? , but i have more than 5 images, they dont have the same size or the same view that i want different

Comment: is different, 

but i want to change only black color and keep other color

Comment: ok.. you should try this....  take one view that covers full image and then you     can set alpha with the condition that if color == black else  don't change color