# Can I change a color within an image in Swift

Tags: swift, core-graphics

Let's say I have an image of a person. I want to change his / her hair color. Or, I would like to be able to select all points with color A and replace them with color B. Is this possible? I'd appreciate pointers (no pun intended. sorta).

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046643/how-to-change-a-particular-color-in-an-image

Comment: Thanks a ton. That was exactly what I was looking for.