# Quartz core : Changing whole layer pixels color

Tags: ios, quartz-core

I'm developping an app that paint on layers. Here's a sample code which show the way I paint.

```
UIImageView * currentLayer = // getting the right layer...
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(currentLayer.frame.size);
[currentLayer.image drawInRect:currentLayer.bounds];
// Painting...
UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
currentLayer.image = img;
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

So I have an image (1024x768) which have two kinds of pixels:
- painted ones (same colour for each)
- transparent ones

What is the best way to change the color of the whole layer opaque pixels, knowing that all pixels have the same color?

Do I have to redraw each opaque pixel one by one?

**EDIT :**

as David Rönnqvist suggested, is tryed by masking a filled image with my layer.

The layer which I want to change color is `self.image` :

```
// Creating image full of color
CGRect imRect = self.bounds;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imRect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
CGContextFillRect(context, imRect);
UIImage * fill = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

// masking the image
CGImageRef maskRef = [self.image CGImage];
CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);

CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask([fill CGImage], mask);
self.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];
```

Almost ! It masks the exact oposite of my layer: only alpha pixels are painted...

Any idea ?

Comment: Do you want to change every pixel or just the opaque pixels?

Comment: You could use the layer with the drawing as the mask to a new layer that is completely filled with the new colour. The alpha value will be used to let through the r,g,b values into the new layer. You need to check the performance thought. I'm not sure how it would scale when you have many layers that big being masked. Also, the layer being used to mask can't be part of the view hierarchy any more.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It sounds me a bit complicated. What about filters ?

Comment: You could draw them with Core Graphics using the blend mode `kCGBlendModeColor` but that will not give you the exact result you are after since it will use the brightness from the one and the color from the other.

Comment: Please see my edit, corresponding to your first propositon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was very simple, in fact.

UIImage has a method : `drawInRect` which only draws opaque pixels.

Here's the code (called from an `UIImageView`):

```
CGRect rect = self.bounds;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
[self.image drawInRect:rect];
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeSourceIn);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, newColor.CGColor);
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Many thanks to [iPhone - How do you color an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223340/iphone-how-do-you-color-an-image)