# setTint on UICell returns a solid color

Tags: objective-c

Im trying to set the tint color for an image before setting it as the background for a UICell, however it only returns a solid color based on my UIColor

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }
    UIImage *testImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageName.png"];
    testImage = [testImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
    UIImageView *testView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:testImage];

    [testView setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    cell.backgroundView = testView;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the cell is showing up as a solid color, that means the image itself is opaque.  `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate` bases the color of each pixel on the alpha channel present in the image for that pixel (i.e., if there's no transparency, you'll get a solid color).  You can read more about this [in the documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIView-SW7).

Comment: I see. What I don't understand is that all sources Ive read on the matter say that to change the color tint of the image then the above code is sufficient. How do I go about tinting an image then?

Comment: According to this post it should be viable? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223340/iphone-how-do-you-color-an-image/4630136#4630136

Comment: I implemented this category and I'm having the same problem with a solid color http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223340/iphone-how-do-you-color-an-image/27356928#27356928

Comment: @justMike The image has to be transparent where you want no color, and opaque where you want color.  Can you share your image?

Comment: @justMike To be clear, the code is correct, it's the image that is causing you problems.

Comment: Thanks Charles, I think I've been expecting a different result, I have since gone with a color overlay. Thanks for you help.